# "File error" when using xclip

Tags: clipboard

To enable copy and paste between X11 and emacs in terminal, I installed xclip via `M-x package-install`. There is `xclip-1.4` in `~/.emacs.d/` with the following files:

```
xclip-autoloads.el  xclip.el  xclip.elc  xclip-pkg.el  xclip-pkg.elc
```

I also checked the variable `load-path` which has `"~/.emacs.d/elpa/xclip-1.4/"`.

But when I type `M-x xclip-mode` I constantly get `Searching for program: xclip, no such file`. Writing `(xclip-mode 1)` to `~/.emacs` comes to the same result. Can anyone help me debug this?

Comment: Do you have `xclip` installed? What does `(executable-find "xclip")` return?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Thanks! Learned another command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xclip Emacs package depends on the xclip command-line application: https://github.com/astrand/xclip. The xclip application is usually provided by Linux distributions so you should look at your package manager first.

If you can't make xclip work or want to try something different, may I suggest my own Emacs package? https://gitlab.petton.fr/DamienCassou/gpastel. This one requires GPaste to be installed on the system (your package manager probably has it too).

Comment: Thanks! It was my misunderstanding. It works well now :)